# Compiz live wallpaper plug-ins, where and how for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz, desktop-background, plugins

I have been looking on a few sites at live wallpaper plug-ins for compiz, but am un able to find a good tutorial for installation, many are very old, or a good list of known plug-ins.

Has any one used these ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is No i havent used them.

The [Compiz wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) is a good place to start for up to date references to what your looking for

Comment: This was a good source of information and did lead to a solution

Comment: Good stuff :-) Glad it helped